# lua not doing string

Tags: c++, lua

I'm trying to get lua 5.1 to execute a line which is just a call to one of my c++ functions `"Assail"` I don't understand why it does not work, can anybody point out the mistakes?

this is the Assail Function:

```
static int Assail(lua_State *L)
{
    cout << "test" << endl;
    return 1;
}
```

I'm trying to call `do_string` like this:

```
L = lua_open();
luaL_openlibs(L);
lua_register(L, "Assail", Assail);
luaL_dostring(L, "s = Assail()");   
lua_close(L);
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: What went wrong? Anyway, check the return code of `luaL_dostring`. Finally, note that `Assail` should probably return 0, since it does not push anything onto the stack. For a surprise, try `s = Assail(10,20); print(s)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're writing this in C++, name mangling is applied to the function, so it will have a special name in the final executable/library that is different from that Lua would expect. You can resolve this by changing its linkage to C using the `extern` keyword:

```
extern "C" int Assail(lua_State *L);

extern "C" int Assail(lua_State *L)
{
    // code here
}
```